# Persistent Connection with 2.4.27 Apache Reverse Proxy Not Working

Tags: apache, connection, reverse-proxy, keep-alive, persistent

I am using Apache/2.4.27 on Fedora 25 as reverse proxy. It was working very well until I hit a persistent connection.
I am using default ProxyPass configuration with only two urls : ProxyPass /myurl http:///myurl

When the client sends a GET request to reverse proxy (this GET request does not include Connection header), it sends the GET request to origin server with adding "Connection: Keep-Alive" header.
Everything is OK untill now. Then server sends 401 Unauthorized response to client over reverse proxy (this response does not include Connection header).

Then client sends a new GET request including Authorization header to reverse proxy (This Get request does not include Connection header) over the same TCP connection. 
And this time reverse proxy does not send this GET request to origin server, so flow does not continue. 10 seconds later origin server enters timeout and ends the connection.
I have searched over internet but could not find any solution this and debug logs tell nothing. By the way client, reverse proxy and origin server using HTTP 1.1 and as I know connection:keep-alive is default for this version.

I have added "disablereuse Off" option. In this case reverse proxy was sending the GET request to origin server by adding "Connection:close"  header. Because of this, origin server is closing the connection 
after sent 401 Unauthorized response. So, reverse proxy establishes a new connection in order to send second GET request and is able to send this request successfully to origin server.

As I want to use persistent connection, I would like to ask that how can I run this feature? Is there any misconfiguration by my side?

Regards